# Python, append txt lines between keywords to another txt

Tags: python, string, file, copy, save

Not an experienced user here.

I have a text file (export.txt) that goes:

```
*NODE
several thousand lines like this one
several thousand lines like this one
several thousand lines like this one
*ANY OTHETR WORD
```

I want to copy the lines between these two keywords (both unfortunatly starting with "*") to the end of another file (original.txt).

Tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632342/extract-string-between-characters-from-a-txt-file-in-python) but am getting an error when trying to copy the data:

```
* * * "Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myscript.py", line 28, in <module>
for line in f:
File "/opt/ansa_15.2.3/meta_post_v15.2.3/../shared_v15.2.3/python/linux64/lib/python3.3/codecs.py",
line 300, in decode (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 267: invalid continuation byte"
* * *
```

May ask for a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: 3. Cannot be more specific as it is an interpreter that is built inside another application.

Comment: Ah yes, I see the obvious now, it's early morning still here... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type

```
str = unicode(str, errors='replace')
```

OR

```
str = unicode(str, errors='ignore')
```

**Note**: This solution will strip out (ignore) the characters in question returning the string without them. Only use this if your need is to strip them not convert them.

Alternatively, use the open method from the codecs module to read in the file:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(file_name, "r",encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as fdata:
```